# Siri Intent Query input field not available when editing Intent scheme in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sirishortcuts

I am writing an app extension for Siri Shortcuts. I'd like to debug it in Xcode and use the option to specify the Siri Intent Query phrase in Run options in Xcode, but the edit field does not show up.

This is the input field I am looking for:

[image: This is how it should look like]

And for my Intent App Extension it is not visible:

[image]

I did restart Xcode but it did not help.

I'm using Xcode 10.2.1. I remember using this option in an older Xcode version.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Ok I found the problem. You have to at least once run the Intent inside Siri (set Executable to 'Ask on Launch' and choose Siri when prompted). 
When you enter the 'Edit Scheme' dialog again, the option appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the problem. You have to at least once run the Intent inside Siri (set Executable to 'Ask on Launch' and choose Siri when prompted). When you enter the 'Edit Scheme' dialog again, the option appears.